# marquee not completing the cycle using css3

Tags: html, css

I have created a marquee , but the problem is marquee is not completing, i have 5 items , but when the maruqee reaches the fourth item or third item it starts the next cycle,

Am i missing something on the below code.

i have achieved this much. Also is this is the best way to achieve this

```css
.students-container ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.students-container .student-container{
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.students-container .student-container  a{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}   

.students-container .student-container .student-profile-image-container img{
    object-fit: contain;
    display: block;
    max-width: 230px;
    max-height: 95px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.student-container:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* Make it move! */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { top:   8em }
    100% { top: -11em }
}
```

```html
<div class="students-container">
  <ul class="students-list">
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated :)

Please see the  [pen](https://codepen.io/mmdileepthomas/pen/ZRaPKy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the end position of the animation has to be equal to the height of all containers combined ( 5x 95px). So all will move up until all dissapear. So that is about `500px`

Otherwise the items will move up but not enough distance so every item dissapears out of the screen before returning back.

Also added the hover event on the parent container. SO all items stop moving when one is hovered. Otherwise the hovered item will stop moving, but the rest will keep moving and that would cause a mess.

```css
.students-container ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.students-container .student-container{
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
}

.students-container .student-container  a{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}   

.students-container .student-container .student-profile-image-container img{
    object-fit: contain;
    display: block;
    max-width: 230px;
    max-height: 95px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.students-container:hover .student-container{
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* Make it move! */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { top:   6em }
    100% { top: calc(-500px - 6em) }
}
```

```html
<div class="students-container">
  <ul class="students-list">
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run the `animation` on the *parent element*, therefore `.students-list`, to prevent the running of the children, adjust the *positioning* of the `animation` to make it run full cycle, and calculate the `height` of the *parent* based on the defined `max-height` of `95px` + `margin-bottom` of 15px, five times, therefore `550px`:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

.students-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 550px; /* 5 x (95px max-height + 15px margin-bottom) */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid; /* just for demo */
}

.students-list {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

.student-container a {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.student-profile-image-container img {
  object-fit: contain;
  display: block;
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 95px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.students-list:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0%   {bottom: -100%}
  100% {bottom: 100%}
}
```

```html
<div class="students-container">
  <ul class="students-list">
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `infinite` from your animation

```css
.students-container ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.students-container .student-container{
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 15s linear;
}

.students-container .student-container  a{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}   

.students-container .student-container .student-profile-image-container img{
    object-fit: contain;
    display: block;
    max-width: 230px;
    max-height: 95px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.student-container:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* Make it move! */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { top:   8em }
    100% { top: -11em }
}
```

```html
<div class="students-container">
  <ul class="students-list">
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="student-container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="student-profile-image-container">
       <img src="https://studentprivacypledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SPP_Pledge_2-1500x900.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="student-details-container">
           It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```